# Get records with more than one value and at least one of them is zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Create table #Tbl
(
ID int not null,
Keyword nvarchar(max)
)
Insert into #Tbl Values ('0','Cryptography')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('1','Cryptography')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('4','Cryptography')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('0','SQL')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('0','SQL')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('3','Cloud Computing')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('6','Recursion')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('8','Recursion')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('0','Universe')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('0','Universe')
Insert into #Tbl Values ('7','Universe')
```

I need to get the titles which has more than one ID and at least one of the ID is zero.

So the expected result will be:

```
Cryptography
Universe
```

I tried below query but not able to add "at least one id is zero" condition

```
select Keyword,COUNT(distinct id) from #Tbl
group by Keyword
having COUNT(distinct id)>1
```

How can I proceed here ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your IDs start from 0, the below should work

```
select Keyword,COUNT(distinct id) from #Tbl
group by Keyword
having COUNT(distinct id)>1 and MIN(id) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this, one example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Keyword
FROM #Tbl T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Tbl WHERE Keyword = T.Keyword
              AND ID = 0)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Tbl WHERE Keyword = T.Keyword
              AND ID != 0)
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e099/3) with a demo.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
SELECT Keyword
FROM  #Tbl
WHERE Keyword IN (SELECT DISTINCT Keyword FROM #Tbl WHERE ID = 0)
GROUP BY Keyword
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another approach:

```
SELECT Keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM #Tbl
GROUP BY Keyword
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > ALL (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(ID, 0)) UNION ALL SELECT 1)
;
```